# How to write a function template that takes a comparison opertator as a parameter?

Tags: c++

I was given the task to write a function template that takes an interval as the first 2 arguments, and a comparison operator as the 3rd argument, and decide if it's monotonic or not using this comparison operator.

Examples for usage:

1.

```cpp
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

monotonic(a, a+10, std::greater<int>())
```

2. 

```cpp
const char *a[] = { "apple", "cherry", "plum", "pickle" };
std::vector<std::string> s(a, a+4);
std::ostream_iterator<std::string> os(cout, ", ");
std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), os);

monotonic(s.begin(), s.end(), std::greater<std::string>())
```

I've been Googleing a lot, and figured out that the template is supposed to look something like this:

```cpp
template<class Iter, typename Comparator>
bool monotonic(Iter first, Iter last, Comparator comp){

}
```

However, I cannot figure out how I'm supposed to use this `comp` to actually compare the numbers, characters, etc.

Comment: You _call_ it. `comp(*first, *(first + 1));`

Comment: Call it like a function call with 2 parametrs.

Comment: Isn't this just  std::find_if_not != last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to design API and write code is by using tests.

```cpp
template<typename T, typename F = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type>>
bool isMonotonic(T b, T e, F cmp = {})
{
    if (b == e) return true;
    auto last = b++;
    while (b != e) {
        if (!cmp(*last, *b)) return false;
        last = b++;
    }
    return true;
}

TEST_CASE("isMonotonic") {
    constexpr int growingTale[] = { 1, 2, 7, 10, 22};
    constexpr int notDecrasingTale[] = { 2, 2, 2, 10, 22};

    SECTION("Empty range is alawyas monotonic") {
        auto sameBeginEnd = std::begin(growingTale);
        CHECK(isMonotonic(sameBeginEnd, sameBeginEnd));
        CHECK(isMonotonic(sameBeginEnd, sameBeginEnd, std::greater{}));
    }
    SECTION("One element range is always monotonic") {
        auto b = std::begin(growingTale);
        CHECK(isMonotonic(b, b + 1));
        CHECK(isMonotonic(b, b + 1, std::greater{}));
    }
    SECTION("growing table is monotonic for less operator, but is not for greater operator") {
        auto b = std::begin(growingTale);
        auto e = std::end(growingTale);
        CHECK(isMonotonic(b, e));
        CHECK(!isMonotonic(b, e, std::greater{}));
    }
    SECTION("Not decrasing range is not monotonic, unless <= operator is used") {
        auto b = std::begin(notDecrasingTale);
        auto e = std::end(notDecrasingTale);
        CHECK(!isMonotonic(b, e));
        CHECK(!isMonotonic(b, e, std::greater{}));
        CHECK(isMonotonic(b, e, std::less_equal{}));
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5zbETxTqx